# How to change default color of ngbTooltip?

Tags: html, angular, ng-bootstrap

This is where I used ngbTooltip. How to change its color of text and background.

```
<a class="dropdown-item" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal3" placement="end"
ngbTooltip="Will wait for action on file">Wait for a file</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply custom css in tooltip by adding a class to it.

```
<a ngbTooltip="Will wait for action on file" tooltipClass="my-custom-class">Wait for a file</a></li>
```

In your CSS :

```
.my-custom-class .tooltip-inner {
    background-color: your-background-color-here;
    color: your-text-color-here;
 }

 .my-custom-class.bs-tooltip-top .tooltip-arrow::before {
     border-top-color: your-background-color-here;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class in your html

```
<a class="dropdown-item"  data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal3" placement="end"
[ngbTooltip]="Will wait for action on file" [tooltipClass]="mytooltip">Wait for a file</a></li>
```

and in your component.css

```
:host ::ng-deep mytooltip {
//whatever you want 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

after spending some time with ngbtooltip I have fixed ngbtooltip arrow background color

```
.bs-tooltip-top .tooltip-arrow::before, .bs-tooltip-auto[data-popper-placement^=top] .tooltip-arrow::before {
  border-top-color: #0062A2 !important;
}
```